# SMD Component Identification 6 pin with diode properties

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount, markings

I am having a difficult time trying to identify the following 6 pin SMD component:

[image]
[image]

I have been searching for what it might be, or the company who made it but have had no luck thus far.  It seems to have diode qualities, such as current flow from pins 2 and 5 (GND) of the to any of the other unknown pins (aprox 0.7 v on diode mode)

The PCB is used in a stair lift with 24V and a DC motor. There are a total of 4 of these unknown components on the PCB. Three here near a micro controller:

[image: 3]

The fourth of theses unknown components has both GND pins (2,5) connected to the negative side of electrolytic capacitor, which is connected to a 18V linear voltage regulator. (Unknown component desoldered in picture)

[image]

Pin 1 and pin 6 of this component are connected to switches that enable the chair to travel up/down the stairs along with safety switches.

When powered on, pin 1 is 1.2V, and pins 3,4,6 are 4.94V and they all should be 3.3V; which lead me to believe this unknown component may be faulty.

If anyone is able to identify this component, that would be a great help.

Comment: The dot in the lower left hand corner makes me think that pin 1 is there, not on the other side as you show.

Comment: Can you include some more of the circuit around it? Perhaps make out if it's a switching regulator, comparator or opamp?

Comment: It may be an ESD protection diode array.  They are available in that footprint and pinout and there are not a lot of other chips with two grounds and no VCC (assumed) connection.

Comment: My bet is on ESD as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"K5" identifies the [PESD5V0S4UD](https://www.nexperia.com/products/esd-protection-tvs-filtering-and-signal-conditioning-esd-protection/general-purpose-esd-protection-devices/PESD5V0S4UD.html), a 5 V ESD protection diode array made by <strike>Philips</strike> <strike>NXP</strike> Nexperia:

[image: PESDxS4UD]